# AngularJs routing not reload script

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, routes

I have a problem with routing.

When the routing changes the scripts included in the head do not work within the template is loaded, it is as if the functions are disabled or absent.

**main.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myapp">
<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">

    <title>Site</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style1.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style3.css">

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-rc1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="routes.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="script2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="script3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <base href="/"></base>

</head>

<body>

    <div class="page" ng-view ng-controller="myappCtrl" anim-class></div>

</body>
</html>
```

**routes.js**

```
'use strict';

var app = angular.module("myapp", [
    "ngRoute",
    "ngAnimate"
]);


// ROUTE CONFIG
app.config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){

    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
      enabled: true,
      requireBase: false
    });
    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');

  $routeProvider.
    when("/dashboard", {
      templateUrl: "dashboard.php",
      controller: "dashboardCtrl",
      animate: "slide-left"
    }).
    when("/associati", {
      templateUrl: "associati.php",
      controller: "associatiCtrl",
      animate: "slide-left"
    }).
    otherwise({
      redirectTo: "/dashboard"
    });

}]);

// PAGE ANIMATE DIRECTIVE
app.directive('animClass',function($route){
  return {
    link: function(scope, elm, attrs){
      var enterClass = $route.current.animate;
      elm.addClass(enterClass)
      scope.$on('$destroy',function(){
        elm.removeClass(enterClass)
        elm.addClass($route.current.animate)
      })
    }
  }
});

/************************************************
**************** CONTROLLER *********************
************************************************/

// MAIN CONTROLLER
app.controller("myappCtrl", function($rootScope, $scope, $location) {

});

// DASHBOARD CONTROLLER
app.controller("dashboardCtrl", function($scope) {

});

// ASSOCIATI CONTROLLER
app.controller("associatiCtrl", function($scope) {

});
```

Every time you change the css files are included page regularly while js no longer work.

Suggestions?

Comment: 1. Hi, you can try add your scripts before </body>, 2. If you use localhost, will be better if you download libs into local path, 3. <div ng-controller="myCtrl as vm"><ng-view>

Comment: I tried but nothing changes, any other ideas? Thanks